# Test for convexity in one variable in a multivariate function

Tags: convex-analysis

I know that to test convexity of a multivariate function $f(x, y)$, you have to check the Hessian. However, how can you check convexity in *one* variable (say *x*)? Is it enough to check $\frac{\partial f^2(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\geq0?$